Question Related to Probabilistic Turing Machine
Q) Assume that the success probability of a probabilistic algorithm $M$. In other words, a
probabilistic Turing machine, satisfies $p_{succ} \geq \frac{1}{p(n)}$, for some polynomial $p(n)= O(n^c)$ where $c$ non-negative. Show that the algorithm $M'$ obtained
by repeating the algorithm $n^d$ times where $d \geq c$ has an error probability $p'_{err}$ given by $p'_{err} \leq e^{-Cn^{d-c}}$ for some positive $C$.
I am struggling to solve this, kinda stuck without how to use given assumptions and connecting them all the way through to the last statement. I need to understand this proof ASAP for a quiz so any and all help would be appreciated.

I presume the implicit assumption here is that "success" in multiple trials means having success in one or more of the trials. Use the inequality $(1-x)^y \le e^{-xy}$ for $y>0$ and $0\le x \le1.$

Which part of the proof do I use this for? I know this relates to the error probability, but I cannot relate the probabilistic algorithm $M$ to this new $M'$

The probability of getting an error all $n^d$ times is $(p_{err})^{n^d}= (1-p_{succ})^{n^d}.$

What is the context where you encountered this?  Can you credit the source where you saw this?  Please see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

@D.W.This is from a question set that a friend sent me, I do not actually think this comes from any text book, but it is from a CS course at his university relating to quantum computation
